# Is it normal or required for POTUS to attended SCOTUS swearing in ceremonies?

Tags: united-states, law

I noticed from the recent swearing in photos of the new SCOTUS judge that POTUS was present.  Is it normal for POTUS to be present?  It is *required* or a choice by someone (who makes that choice?).  Of course I don't even know if there is a rule saying POTUS should not be present (seems unlikely).

But what are the requirements and/or accepted norms for this process?

Comment: POTUS picked them for the job so I don't see why they wouldn't attend.

Comment: @JoeW as far as I can Obama was not present at either of his nominees' swearing in ceremonies.  https://www.scotusblog.com/2009/08/sotomayor-sworn-in-as-associate-justice/ and https://www.scotusblog.com/2010/08/kagan-sworn-in-as-112th-justice/constitutional-oath-of-elena-kagan/

Comment: I can't tell you what the norm is, but I can tell you that the President was there this time likely because the ceremony was held at the White House.

Comment: President Trump was present at [Kavanaugh's](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brett_Kavanaugh) and [Gorsuch's](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neil_Gorsuch) ceremonies. @Jontia: my impression is that judicial appointments were a much larger part of Trump's platform (and appeal) in 2016 than of Obama's in 2008 and 2012, so it makes sense for Trump to be more likely to attend "his" appointee's ceremonies. Same, of course, for Coney Barrett right before the election.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

It's entirely normal and proper. It isn't required but the oath is often taken at the White House, so if the President is in Washington they would normally attend.  If they are not in Washington they may choose to return or not. But there's no constitutional requirement for anyone but the confirmee and a person to administer the oath.

GW Bush was present at the swearing-in of Justice Roberts.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ubp2F3WD68A